# How to use multiple form elements in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I would like to create a view with a text box for each item in a collection. How do I do this, and how do I capture the information when it POSTs back? I have used forms and form elements to build static forms for a model, but never dynamically generated form elements based on a variable size collection.

I want to do something like this in mvc 3:

```
@foreach (Guest guest in Model.Guests)
{
    <div>
        First Name:<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(???) @* I can't do x => x.FirstName here because
                                 the model is of custom type Invite, and the
                                 lambda wants to expose properties for that
                                 type, and not the Guest in the foreach loop. *@
    </div>
}
```

How do I do a text box for each guest? And how do I capture them in the action method that it posts back to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show us how the Guest class looks like? And what is Model.Guests? List<Guest> ?

Comment: The guest class is dymaically generated by entity framework. Just has some properties on it such as FirstName, LastName, Id, InviteId, etc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Definitely a job for an editor template. So in your view you put this single line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Guests)
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Guest.cshtml`)

```
@model AppName.Models.Guest
<div>
    First Name:<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
</div>
```

And that's about all.

Now the following actions will work out of the box:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    SomeViewModel model = ...
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // TODO: do something with the model your got from the view
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Note that the name of the editor template is important. If the property in your view model is:

```
public IEnumerable<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
```

the editor template should be called `Guest.cshtml`. It will automatically be invoked for each element of the `Guests` collection and it will take care of properly generating ids and names of your inputs so that when you POST back everything works automatically.

Conclusion: everytime you write a loop (`for` or `foreach`) inside an ASP.NET MVC view you should know that you are doing it wrong and that there is a better way.

Comment: What if I want a different editor for different areas? i.e. I want a different editor for Guest in the admin section, with more options than the editor for Guest in the public secion.

Comment: Nevermind. Html.EditorFor() has an overload with editor name. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Chevex, then in the Admin section provide the corresponding editor template: `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Guest.cshtml`.

Comment: @Chevex, no, try to avoid this overload. Use conventions instead. It's better and most developers should already be familiar with conventions.

Comment: Gotcha thanks for the help. I am now having a different issue. Maybe you can help? I have created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072905/dropdownlist-not-populating-with-correct-value-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guests.Count; i++) {
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Guests.ToList()[i].FirstName)
}
```

There are more examples and details on [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) by Haacked.

**UPDATE:** The controller post action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Room room)
{
    return View();
}
```

In this example I'm considering that you have a Room class like this:

```
public class Room
{
    public List<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
}
```

That's all, on the post action, you should have the Guests list correctly populated.

Comment: I like! Mind showing me how to capture this on the other side in the action method after the POST?

Comment: Read up on model binding. It's easier than you think. https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+mvc+model+binding

Comment: Updated. By the way, the post I linked above had this answer.