# MVC3, Get updated form data from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strongly-typed view, with a list of custom objects in the model.

In the view I display textboxes for every object in the list :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Localization", FormMethod.Post))
{
        foreach (YB.LocalizationGlobalText m in Model.GlobalTexts)
    { 
            @Html.Label(m.LocalizationGlobal.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => m.Text)
            <br />
    }   
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now how would I get the updated data from the textboxes in my model.
I can see in the formcollection the updated data is there:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult SaveData(FormCollection form)
    {
        // Get movie to update
        return View();
   }
```

form["m.Text"] = "testnewdata1,testnewdata"

But how do I get this mapped to the model, so I have the updated values for each object.
Or how can I get it cleanly from the formcollection, something like this .. form[someid]["m.Text"]

Edit:

I also tried passing the model as a parameter, but the model data is empty.

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult SaveData(LocalizationModel model, FormCollection form)
        {
            // Get movie to update
            return View();
       }
```

When I look into the model: model.GlobalTexts = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult SaveData(int movieId, FormCollection form)
{
    // Get movie to update
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Where(x => x.Id == movieId);
    // Update movie object with values from form collection.
    TryUpdateModel(movie, form);
    // Do model validation
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();
    return View("success");
}
```

**Edit** See this question I asked a while back: [How to use multiple form elements in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070399/how-to-use-multiple-form-elements-in-asp-net-mvc)

Lets say you have a view like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomObject>

@foreach (CustomObject customObject in Model)
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox(customObject.CustomProperty);
        <!-- etc etc etc -->
    </div>
}
```

Refactor it like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomObject>

    @for (int count = 0; count < Model.Count(); count++)
    {
        <div>
            <!-- Add a place for the id to be stored. -->
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[count].Id);

            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[count].CustomProperty);
            <!-- etc etc etc -->
        </div>
    }
```

Now in your action method do this:

```
public virtual ActionResult SaveData(IEnumerable<CustomObject>)
{
    // You now have a list of custom objects with their IDs intact.
}
```

It's even easier than that if you use editors, but I'll let you figure those out for yourself as they are super simple. The accepted answer in the question I linked shows an example.

**NOTE:** you can substitute IList for IEnumerable if you need to.

Comment: And how would I get the id ? I'm trying to save every object, not just one.

Comment: I will update with an edit. Hole on. I forgot you were dealing with a list of objects.

Comment: Quickly tried implementing the EditorFor example from the link, the view fills but when saving again the data is null. I'll continue tomorrow, probably overlooked something obvious ..

Comment: I got it working now using a combination, but I still find it strange that in my Action I need to pass an IEnumerable for it to work. If I pass the model all values are null. Event hough my view is strongly typed to the model, not the list.

Comment: You don't have to pass IEnumerable, you could add an IEnumerable or IList of CustomObject as a property of a view model and then pass the view model to the view. See the question I linked for an example because my page uses the model `Invite` and the models I want to create editors for are of type `Guest`. `Invite` has property `Guests` which is an `IEnumerable<Guest>`

Comment: Just to clarify - the reason a **for** loop has to be used instead of a **foreach** is because the `@Html.HiddenFor`, `@Html.TextBoxFor` etc. methods use reflection of the property name (i.e. `x[count].Id`) to generate form field names. Since there's no explicit index involved when you use **foreach**, all fields end up with identical names & MVC can't reinterpret the postback into individual items. Using the example above, the **foreach** loop would produce this: `<input name="customObject.Id" ... />`, while the **for** loop would produce this: `<input name="[1].Id" .. />`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use your viewmodel as a parameter of SaveData, and it will map it automatically:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult SaveData(ViewModelType viewmodel)
{
    // Get movie to update
    return View();
}
```