# ASP.NET MVC 3 Display Template problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

First I have a Display Template in Views > Blog > DisplayTemplates:

```
@model Domain.Model.BlogPost
<div class="blogSummary">
    @Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "post", new { Id = Model.PostID }, new { @class = "titleLink" })
    <div class="subInfo">
        Posted by @Model.Author on @Model.PostedDate.ToString("D") | @Model.PostComments.Count
        Comment(s)</div>
    <br />
    <div class="summaryText">
        @Html.Markdown(Model.Body.Length > 300 ? Model.Body.Remove(0, 300) + "..." : Model.Body)
        @Html.ActionLink("(view more)", "post", new { Id = Model.PostID })
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Model.BlogPost>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "BlogPostSummary")
```

However, I am getting an error on the `DisplayFor()`:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[Domain.Model.BlogPost]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'Domain.Model.BlogPost'.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what's going on. What is the best way to use the display template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to pass in a collection of BlogPosts, when a single BlogPost is expected.

Try:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[0], "BlogPostSummary")
```

Or something like:

```
@foreach (var post in Model)
    @Html.Display(post)
```

Note: I'm not convinced the second example is using Html.Display correctly. My suspicion is that the code would be better served using a partial instead of a display template.

**UIHint**

By default, ASP.NET MVC relies on naming conventions to link `BlogPost` the class to BlogPost.cshtml the display template. If however, you would like to use CustomBlogPost.cshtml as your display template, you can do so by applying the `UIHint` attribute.

```
public class DomainModel {
    [UIHint("CustomBlogPost")]
    public BlogPost Post { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. In another app I have, I did this `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Guests)` and it worked just fine. The model of the view was of type `Invite` which had a navigation property `Guests` of type `EntityCollection<Guest>`. I was not iterating over the collection; it did it automatically :/

Comment: My feeling is on this one though, that you should be using a partial instead of a display template. Is there any reason why you haven't?

Comment: No reason, I was just told in another question somewhere to avoid looping through collections in my views and to use templates. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070399/how-to-use-multiple-form-elements-in-asp-net-mvc That's where he told me to use editors and display templates.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that functionality, but it doesn't seem to be applicable to display templates.

Comment: It is. I just figured it out. It's because of the naming convention. When I renamed my display template to BlogPost.cshmtl it all started working. This just sucks because I don't want that to be the default display template.

Comment: This is getting too tedious. I am just going to use partial views as you said. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, the template needs to be named the same as the intended model. This can be overridden with domain models using the `UIHint` attribute though.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of that info?

Comment: `UIHint` is contained within the Data Annotations namespace. I've provided a brief summary in my answer, but more info can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see. Same issue though. It assumes I only ever want to use ONE template. Doesn't give me the option to specify several templates. I'll stick with partial view for now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this maybe

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.First(), "BlogPostSummary")
```

Comment: Not sure why `[UIHint(...)]` doesn't work in MVC 5.x but the above worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on the same problem, and I think I have a better solution for you.  You *can* loop through the collection and still get this to work:

```
@foreach(var blogPost in Model)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(x => blogPost, "BlogPostSummary")
}
```

Using a variable on the left side of a lambda expression doesn't necessarily require you to also use it on the right side.  `DisplayFor` expects an `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`.  TModel is the type of your model, such as `IEnumerable<BlogPost>`, but TValue can be anything you like.  So as long as you have a reference to the current item in your collection, as in the foreach above, you can ignore the left side of the lambda expression.

(But you do have to *have* the TModel.  `Html.DisplayFor(() => blogPost, "BlogPostSummary")` doesn't work.)

Comment: Right I was aware I could loop in this manner (though it seems hackish and probably better suited to partial views). My issue was that I loved how the display template automatically detected that it was being passed a collection of it's model type and did the looping/repeating implicitly. Unfortunately, this only works if you use the proper naming convention for templates. Which means only one template per type, and I needed more than one template per type. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I'm actually doing something like this right now, and the above syntax, while it seems like it *should* work, will not. You will be able to step into your Template, but the generated html will *never* get rendered. You have to prepend `Html.DisplayFor()` with `@`. Typically this would get you the `once in a code block you don't need to prepend statements with '@'` error, but apparently there are some special rules.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412113/mvc4-razor-displaytemplate-called-html-generated-but-not-rendered-to-browser

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's because doing an `@Html.DisplayFor()` implicitly tells MVC that the Model to pass on is the Model of the passing View, i.e. `IEnumerable<Domain.Model.BlogPost>`

What you need to do is enumerate over the Model, and display each of them:

```
@foreach(var blogPost in Model){

    Html.RenderPartial("BlogPostSummary", blogPost)

}
```

Make sure the BlogPostSummary is in the correct folder, and you should be good to go!