# Modelbinding IEnumerable in ASP.NET MVC POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, model-binding

Is there any issues with modelbinding IEnumerable types to an MVC POST?

Some properties in my Model are not being bound upon a post to an action. Seems that properties on the model like strings are ok, but my IEnumerable is what is not being bound.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.Test) %>
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities.Count(); i++)
    {%>
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities.ToArray()[i].BandName) %>
  <% } %>
```

And here is what those properties look like in the model:

```
public IEnumerable<BandAvailabilityInfo> BandAvailabilities { get; set; }
public string Test { get; set; }
```

The view works fine and outputs a list of textboxes with the expected values in them. But the post Action which gets fired only recognises the Test string as a property. The model state does not contain my IEnumerable data either.

Comment: Despite being downvoted, I really hope someone who had similar issues stumbles across this question and gets a better insight into the problem...

Comment: I am not sure.. why many good questions are downvoted without explanations.... I stumbled across this and found useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Model binding depends upon how generated html looks like. for ur particular scenario to bind properly html should look like

```
<input type="text" name = "ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities[0].BandName"/>
<input type="text" name = "ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities[1].BandName"/>
<input type="text" name = "ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities[2].BandName"/>
.
.
<input type="text" name = "ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities[n].BandName"/>
```

i have not tried it but i am almost certain that call to ToArray method in loop is keeping the system from generating proper names for nested inputs. There are couple of things you can do to remedy this
First, in your view model change

```
public IEnumerable<BandAvailabilityInfo> BandAvailabilities { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<BandAvailabilityInfo> BandAvailabilities { get; set; }  //or Array
```

so you don't have to call ToArray method in the loop and proper names are generated for inputs.
Second, make an editor template and put it in Editor templates folder either under the current controller or in shared folder's Editor template folder. Make this view accept model of type `BandAvailabilityInfo` and name of this view should also be `BandAvailabilityInfo`. then in your main view you only have to replace entire loop with

```
 <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.ResponseInfo.SubsetInfo.BandAvailabilities%>
```

and rest will be handled by framework itself

Comment: I'm not sure if it is infact because I use ToArray or not, but changing it to an actual array worked fixed the issue.

Comment: u can inspect generated html and be sure of it

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with the `IEnumarble` type.
 I think the problem is the `ToArray` you are writing inside the `For` loop. (It's very not efficient either)
change the `for` loop to `foreach`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5070583/601179) excellent answer how to achieve it.

Comment: I use a for loop because I need to make TextBoxFors which take a predicate parameter of Model to identify which element of a collection in my model I am making this TextBoxFor for. The index is just a way to keep track of these elements. With a foreach loop I lose context of where the element came from. As far as I know this way is not inefficient in comparison, especially if I use Arrays as the speed is O(1).