# Accessing Partial view element Ids and Names in Master

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, partial-views

I have a few strongly-typed partial views which displays output in a list format. Here is one of the Partials:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student ID
            </th>           
            <th>
                Past Due Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Past Due Days
            </th>            
        </tr>

        <% if (Model != null)
           foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("StudentID",item.StudentID) %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueAmount",item.PastDueAmount) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueDays",item.PastDueDays) %>
            </td>            
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

Here is how I access above partial in master:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SaveStudentInvoice", "StudentInvoice")) %>
<% { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("DisplayStudentInvoiceList"); %>
<input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

Now, I have a "Save" button in master which when I click should save Student ID, Past Due Amount and Past Due Days in a table. How can I access the partial view elements Ids and Names in Master view to do the insert?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should have the save button inside your partial, but you can use JavaScript. Haven't checked but it should be something like `document.forms[0].submit();` unless you have more forms. Than change the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC Views/MasterPages don't do inserts. They display data. It's controller actions that do inserts. The partial view example you have shown is only displaying the student data details as labels. If you want to send them back to the server (for insertion) you should use an HTML `<form>` (`<% using (Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController")) { %>`) and input fields (`Html.EditorFor` helper) instead of simple labels.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I have the controller actions and JS(Ajax) in place. What I dont understand is, how do I access/pass the StudentIds and other details from partials to Controller actions? these fields on partials have no Ids, Also, partials are strongly-typed and the number of rows output is not fixed either.

Comment: A partial should not need to access its parent view information. If it does, it means that you have done something wrong in the separation of your views and partial views.

Comment: Its the Parent trying to access partial, the button to save info from partials is in the Master(Parent) view. How should I approach this?

Comment: You should wrap the partial call inside a form and then have a corresponding controller action that will be invoked when the submit button is clicked. This action will receive the input field values.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be working. One think I am not able to resolve it, I am able to insert the first record from the partial, but not 2nd , 3rd and so on. Should I be looping through the partial view output in controller action(which inserts the data) and saving it one by one? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Could you look into this once? I am struggling with looping through rows in partial view to insert them in DB. Also, I have used Html.Textbox helper instead of Html.EditorFor helper, would this restrict me from achieving what I want?

Comment: It's not clear to what model you want to bind this form. You must respect the [naming convention](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for your input fields if you want to be able to bind it back to a list. Or simply use editor templates and stop writing `foreach` loops which is what I recommend. I have written like millions of other posts about editor templates. Just type mt name and editor templates and foreach loop in google and you will find lots of similar topics. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5070583/29407