# Problems passing a Model from a View to a Controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I bind my `Checkout` View with a Model which I'd like to pass to my `Purchase` controller
to bind to my `Purchase` View.
At the moment when it gets passed, the value is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Checkout View:

```
@model List<BasketModels.Product>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Purchased", "Basket", FormMethod.Post))
{

// problem here
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase"/>
}
```

Purchase controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Purchased(List<BasketModels.Product> products)
```

Product mode:

```
public class BasketModels
    {
        public class Product
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

            public string ImageURL { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
            public int Quantity { get; set; }


            public int Stock { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public decimal Price { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your submit button to just `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` and see how you get on? You shouldn't need all that JS redirection stuff in there

Comment: I don't think using DisplayFor will populate your model

Comment: @CrazyCoderz That line isn't the problem, its the submit button at the bottom

Comment: The onclick event in your submit button is worng. Submit buttons don't need on click handlers. If you click on a submit button the browser will post the data to url which you set in the action attribute of the form element. In your case mvc does that for you with at Html.BeginForm

Comment: @Oliver I took that part out as per Vazes comment but it's still null.

Comment: May this StackOverflow question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070399/how-to-use-multiple-form-elements-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Oliver That is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Can we see your model?

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Posted above

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.modelPropery) quick and dirty route. This is in adittion to your DisplayFor.

Comment: That line isn't the problem, its the submit button at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I tested it using the following and it works.

Checkout View

```
@model ProjectName.Models.BasketModels.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm("Purchased", "Basket", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Description)
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase"/>
}
```

Purchased Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Purchased(BasketModels.Product products)
{
     return View();
}
```

I realize you might still want it to bind as a list. In that case, I've been trying to figure how to do that for days and I don't have a solution. `List<string>` works. `List<model>` does not.